# SAS SQL output ranges of consecutive dates from data table of singular dates

Tags: sql, date, sas

I am attempting to write a SAS/SQL program that will read all of the dates in a column of a particular table, organize those dates in chronological order, check for groupings of consecutive date ranges in the column, then output the start and end dates of each date range.  Each date range corresponds to two other categorical factors: location and car class.

So effectively, I need the ranges of consecutive dates from a table of dates for each car class in each location.

Sample Input:

```
Location           car            length          date
ABC                 C               7           1/13/2014
ABC                 D               10          2/6/2016
ABC                 C                7          1/12/2014
ABC                 D                10         2/7/2016
```

Desired output:

```
Location      Car           length        start date range      end date range
ABC            C              7               1/12/2014             1/13/2014
ABC            D              10              2/6/2016              2/7/2016
```

So effectively, I need to find observations that have equal locations, car types, and lengths then find the date range between them and output the date range with the other classifications.

Comment: Can you show example input and output data?  What have you tried?  Why PROC/SQL instead of a data step?

Comment: I will show sample data in the question. I have tried to use a left join that checks for consecutive dates and I have tried an over(order by ....) statement implementation that did not work as those statements are not valid in PROC SQL

Answer (score 0):

PROC SQL is not really the right tool for this type of problem. Just use a simple data step.

First let's create some sample data and make sure it is sorted. (I prefer to show dates using year, month, day order it eliminates confusion about which part is the day and which is the month.)

```
data have;
  input location $ car $ length date;
  informat date mmddyy.;
  format date yymmdd10.;
cards;
ABC C  7  1/13/2014
ABC D 10  2/6/2016
ABC C  7  1/12/2014
ABC D 10  2/7/2016
ABC C  7  1/25/2014
;;;;
proc sort data=have;
  by location car length date;
run;
```

First make a group variable.

```
data middle;
  set have ;
  by location car length date ;
  if first.length or dif(date) ne 1 then group+1;
  if first.length then group=1;
run;
```

Then take the min and max dates per group.

```
data want ;
  set middle;
  by location car length group;
  if first.group then start_date=date;
  if last.group then stop_date=date;
  if last.group;
  retain start_date;
  format start_date stop_date yymmdd10.;
  drop date;
run;
```

This will result in this table.

```
location    car    length    group    start_date     stop_date
  ABC        C        7        1      2014-01-12    2014-01-13
  ABC        C        7        2      2014-01-25    2014-01-25
  ABC        D       10        1      2016-02-06    2016-02-07
```

With a little work you can probably get it down to single step.

Comment: Where do I specify where the input data is coming from then? middle or have?

Comment: I specified the data input where you have "set have".  However I have gotten errors on the two lines that start with "by location" claiming it is a syntax error. Thus, there is no output when I run the data step

Comment: If you get error messages then you should not not get an output dataset created, as the notes in the log will show.  I cannot see anything wrong with the BY statement was written above. First thing to check in SAS is misplaced semi-colons.  Also HAVE needs to be sorted by the variables in the BY statement or else you will get an error.

Comment: Disagree - Proc SQL is as valid and have probably a cleaner/shorter syntax (in my view) than your solution - Only one `proc sql` is required

Comment: This implementation outputted a results table that contained the date, location, car type, length and count for each observation, but it did not give a start date and an end date for each distinct combination of location, car type, and length. How can I get it to output those date ranges rather than the dates in chronological order?

Answer (score 0):

Seems a pretty straight forward requirement (unless I missing something obvious here).

here is my approach using a single `proc sql`:

```
proc sql;
create table desired_output as select 
    location
    ,car
    ,length
    ,min(date) as start_date_range format=date9.
    ,max(date) as end_date_range format=date9.
from your_input_table
group by 1,2,3;
quit;
```

Comment: you can change date9. for ddmmyy10. if you want do display dates in dd/mm/yyyy format.

Comment: This just gets the start and stop date per vehicle.  It does not solve the actual problem of how to detect the contiguous intervals.

Comment: How do you output the individual ranges once you have a table of dates in chronological order categorized by location, car type, and length?

Comment: your original examples are a bit confusing - looking at @tom solution now I understand your requirement. So my solution is not fit for this problem. Sorry!